# How to display data in node structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, family-tree

I want to make a family tree using mvc. I also need to insert data with relationship.I have object data which I want display with its entities in node structure.Any effort will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Check here for more info about how to ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

There are modules that can help you create a tree. [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/), [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) are good place to start from.

A simple jsTree example using a tree node structure from json (you can also use flat tree structure):

```
<div id="treeContainer"></div>
```

```
$('#treeContainer').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       'Simple root node',
       {
         'text' : 'Root node 2',
         'state' : {
           'opened' : true,
           'selected' : true
         },
         'children' : [
           { 'text' : 'Child 1' },
           'Child 2'
         ]
      }
    ]
} });
```

Comment: I totally agree. This is a very general question, and the answer is a reference to external modules - how would you go about writing essential parts to this question?

Comment: The question itself is very vague and lacking in detail which makes properly answering it highly difficult. I'm sure the modules you mentioned would be helpful, but an answer needs more substance than just the names of a couple useful modules. Perhaps you could provide an example using either or both of those modules.

Comment: Sure - that's a good idea.